# How to restrict the domain to accept only 24 letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex but I wanted to limit to accept only 24 letters in the .domain part.

for example: http://www.google.**comddddddddddddddddddddddddddd** <= this part should limited to 24 characters

```
/(?!-)(?!\.)(?!.*?\.\.)(?![a-zA-Z]+\-\.[a-zA-Z]+)(?![a-zA-Z]+\+[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)(?![a-zA-Z\#]+\/[a-zA-Z\-]+)(?![0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9@%._~#=]+-*[a-zA-Z0-9@%._~#=]+)+.(?!-)[a-z]{2,24}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@%_+.~?&//=:$]*)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to alert the user? If so, the below function should be what you're looking for.

```js
/* regex to return top-level domain from a web address */
function getTLD(url) {
  return url.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?]+)/)[1].match(/^[^\.]+\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
}

function limitTLD(userInput) {
  let tld = getTLD(userInput);
  if (tld.length > 24){

    //return just the first 24 characters
    //return tld.substring(0, 24);
    return `${tld.length} character domain is too long! Please limit to 24 characters`;
  } else {
    return userInput;
  }
}

console.log(limitTLD('http://www.google.comddddddddddddddddddddddddddd'));
```

Or if you're trying to return only the first 24 letters of the domain, `tld.substring(0, 24)` (commented out above) should do the trick.